# Best Approach to Generate Unique Order Number with concurent inserts in Sales Application - Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

We have a sales application where we are generating a unique order number by adding increment in the previous value. Since we are using unique combination based on the orderid and store id, we can not use auto increment. However sometime we are getting duplicate order ids if request is submitted from multiple client devices.

Can you please advise the better way to handle an order id generation based on order id and store id? We are using PHP as scripting language.

This is what we have as of now.

```
// Table Structure

salesorders (Order_id, store_id)

$generatenextorderid = "select max(order_id) + 1 from salesorders where store_id = 1";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just have an incrementing order_id. The store id is just a separate piece of information. Alternatively, use a MyISAM engine, which will accommodate your current logic. As you've spotted, Your current solution is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: The reason, we are doing this as we needed sequence for the order ID per Store ID. The table I have is using MyISAM. Can I create auto increment based on the combination of the keys using auto increment in MyISAM?

Comment: As you want to create store-wise order id, so don't use order id as PK of that table, use auto increment id for order table & for display purpose use the same logic as you have implemented currently.

Comment: "we needed sequence for the order ID per Store ID" Nobody ever needs this. Why are you the exception?